# How to implement C# Extension methods accepting anonymous type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, extension-methods, asp.net-mvc-4

In ASP.NET MVC there are plenty of Helpers accepting anonymous types as argument and generating input.

For example:

```
@Html.Action("Action", "Controler", new {routeVal1 = 1, routeVal2 = 2})
```

My question is how to implement my own extensions accepting anonymous type. Should i reference it as object and use reflection or there is more elegant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) instead of `object`.

> Visual C# 2010 introduces a new type, dynamic. The type is a static type, but an object of type dynamic bypasses static type checking. In most cases, it functions like it has type object. At compile time, an element that is typed as dynamic is assumed to support any operation. Therefore, you do not have to be concerned about whether the object gets its value from a COM API, from a dynamic language such as IronPython, from the HTML Document Object Model (DOM), from reflection, or from somewhere else in the program. However, if the code is not valid, errors are caught at run time.

Comment: I like that! Thanks for the answer. But do this affect performance?

Comment: @Oded How can I get a list of available properties from the dynamic object? How can I access a property later?

Comment: @Fox32 - With `dynamic` you simply call the member. You will get a runtime error if it doesn't exist. You _can't_ get a list of available properties (so no intellisense). That's kinda the point of `dynamic`.

Comment: @Oded Ok, that is what i already know about dynamic, but I thought Nas asked for something different.

Comment: @Fox32 - Not that I can see. The OP is asking how to pass in anonymous types to a method.

Answer (score 1):

right firstly i am assuming you are righting extensions for the 
`@HTML` object
what you need to do is create the method with

RouteValueDictionary class

so it becomes 
public static mvchtmlstring Foo(string Action, string Controller, RouteValueDictionary values)

then you have in the function call

```
        TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("D");
        tb.Attributes.Add();
```

so the whole thing becomes

```
public static mvchtmlstring Foo(string taglabel, string url, RouteValueDictionary values)
{


            TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("a");
tb.Attrubutes.add("href",url);
tb.setInnerText(taglabel);
            tb.MergeAttributes(values);
return new MvcHtmlString(tb.toString());
}
```

then the call is

```
@Html.Foo("Bar","Http://www.stackoverflow.com",new {Id="d", class="dd"})
```

BTW RouteValueDictionary Inherits from IDictionary so your class can have a signature for that too.

Comment: You have missed the this reference :) Never the less that's not essential. Thanks for the reply and bringing another point of view.